# How to move 2d polygon to keep relations between edges?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I need to implement simple 2d polygon editor with special feature, you can give edges special relations:

1. Make two edges perpendicular
2. Freeze edge length (at given state)

The problem is that I don't know how to "repair" polygon when moving one vertex, I mean that when you for example rotate and extend edge which is perpendicular to another edge the second one should adjust (because of relation).

Can you give some advice or sources where I can find similar problems?

Answer (score -1):

e.g. the edge `AB` is perpendicular to some other edge(where, `A` and `B` is vertex name), it means that the direction from `A` to `B` is fixed. let denote this edge direction as `T`.

When vertex `A` is moved, `B` must also be moved to some position in the direction of `T` from the moved `A` position.
To achieve this... divide the move to the 2 components which first one is perpendicular to `T` and second one is the rest. Then apply only the first one to `B`.

Comment: Under the "Freeze edge length state", apply second one too( : A and B move together).

Comment: Now B was moved, but If edge BC is perpendicular to another edge, C also must be moved, and then if edge CD is...

Comment: I think that in the case of FreezeEdge, you assume that we cannot change the angle of the edge which is @fana

Comment: If I misunderstood the problem... please show some concrete example figures.